How to obtain the height of an element after being transformed by the 'transform: rotateY (α)' attribute?
Let's assume there is a style like the following:
.main{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    perspective: 1000px;
}
.page-L{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 30%;
    transform-origin: left;
    transform: rotateY(α);
}
.page-R{
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 70%;
}

If you have any misunderstandings about my question, please take a look at this!!
These two elements are children of “main”.
As you can see, you can clearly see that the element 'page-L' will undergo a deformation, and this will cause a visual change to its right side.
What should I do to obtain its changed value (height) through JavaScript and apply it to the element 'page-R'?

getComputedStyle()

@zer00ne I used it, but it didn't work?

@zer00ne const pageL = document.querySelector('.page-L');const visualHeight = window.getComputedStyle(pageL).height;,This is my code.

You need to clarify the question. The title of your question is "calculate the value of css property transform-rotateY(α)", which seems to indicate that you want to compute α under a constraint. Then you talk about the height of L, but are not satisfied with well known method to compute its height. And mention the right side. Please, be accurate: what exactly do you want to compute.

Actually it's not as intuitive as most methods are: const pageL = document.querySelector('.page-L');const visualRotation = window.getComputedStyle(pageL) then: visualRotation.getPropertyStyle("transform") because the values of transform property need careful diligence. See this article

@zer00ne Sorry, perhaps my statement was not complete enough and caused you some misunderstanding. My requirement is not to obtain the specific value of alpha in 'rotateY (alpha)', but rather to assume that it has rotated by one alpha radian. What I specifically want is to obtain the visual change in the height of the element 'page-L' on its right side after being rotated by an alpha radian, and this value is what I want.

@chrslg Sorry,I want the height of the right side

Ok, that's clearer. But, please, edit your question accordingly (needed details should not be in comments). As for the answer, that is not that easy, because that depends on the "camera" model. I am not sure this is standardized. The easiest way, I would say, is to add some invisible, size 0, elements to get their position

@chrslg lol thanks you good idea!!!!

As I was saying in comment, to measure the right side, you have two option

Understand the projective geometry involved. I am not sure that is even standard (reproducible from one browser to another). Maybe it is.
Basically, the coordinates are passed through a projective matrix, in homogeneous coordinates (that is, in 3D, 4 values (x y z w), that are equivalency classes (x/w, y/w, z/w, 1).

Easier method: place an invisible 0-width witness div at the side of .page-L, and see what is its bounding box. Since it is 0-width, its bounging box height is its real height




function go(){
    let a=parseFloat(document.querySelector('#angle').value);
    document.querySelector('.page-L').style.transform=`rotateY(${a}deg)`;
    const rect = document.querySelector('.sideL').getBoundingClientRect();
    document.querySelector('.page-R').style.height=rect.height+'px';
}
.main{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    height: 80vh;
    background-color:green;
    perspective: 1000px;
}
.page-L{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 30%;
    transform-origin: left;
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
    background-color:red;
}
.sideL{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    height:100%;
    right:0;
    width:0;
}
.page-R{
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 70%;
    background-color: blue;
}
<input id=angle><button onclick="go();">Rotate</button>
<div class=main>
<div class=page-L><div class=sideL></div></div>
<div class=page-R></div>
</div>




Yes, your idea is very correct. I just solved this problem by placing invisible elements with a width of 0. Thank you again!!!

try this again.
    function calculateRightSideHeight() {
    const pageL = document.querySelector('.page-L');

    // Extract the rotation angle from the computed transform style
      const style = window.getComputedStyle(pageL);
      const transform = style.transform;

    if (transform !== 'none') {
       // Parse the matrix to get the rotation angle
          const values = transform.match(/matrix3d\((.+)\)/) || 
     transform.match(/matrix\((.+)\)/);
    if (values) {
        const matrix = values[1].split(', ').map(parseFloat);

        // For rotateY, the matrix element at index [0][0] is cos(α)
                const cosAngle = matrix[0]; // First element of the 
             transform matrix
            const angle = Math.acos(cosAngle); // Angle in radians

             // Calculate the effective height of the right side
             const originalHeight = pageL.offsetHeight;
            const effectiveHeight = originalHeight * 
         Math.abs(Math.cos(angle));

             return effectiveHeight;
        }
    }

     // If no transform or can't calculate, return the original height
     return pageL.offsetHeight;
}

 function updatePageRHeight() {
    const pageR = document.querySelector('.page-R');
    const transformedHeight = calculateRightSideHeight();

    // Set the height of .page-R to match the right side height of 
     .page-L
     pageR.style.height = `${transformedHeight}px`;

}
// Call this function after applying the rotateY transform
updatePageRHeight();


I have tried your method, but the height of R has indeed changed to the height of L, but it is not the height to the right of L (i.e. the height after its change)
